# unable to source user defined python gdb command

Tags: python, gdb

I've been following [this](https://undo.io/resources/gdb-watchpoint/how-write-user-defined-gdb-commands-python/) amazing (video) tutorial to create custom user defined GDB command using python

here is my code

```
import os
import gdb

class BugReport (gdb.Command):
    """Collect required info for a bug report"""

def __init__(self):
    super(BugReport, self).__init__("bugreport", gdb.COMMAND_USER)

def invoke(self, arg, from_tty):
    pagination = gdb.parameter("pagination")
    if pagination: gdb.execute("set pagination off")
    f = open("/tmp/bugreport.txt", "w")
    f.write(gdb.execute("thread apply all backtrace full", to_string=True))
    f.close()
    os.system("uname -a >> /tmp/bugreport.txt")
    if pagination: gdb.execute("set pagination on")

BugReport()
```

but when I try to source this code inside gdb I get following error:

```
(gdb) source mybugreport.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mybugreport.py", line 19, in <module>
    BugReport()
TypeError: function missing required argument 'name' (pos 1)
```

what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what I'm doing wrong?

Python is indentation-sensitive. You want:

```
class BugReport (gdb.Command):
  """Collect required info for a bug report"""

  def __init__(self):
    super(BugReport, self).__init__("bugreport", gdb.COMMAND_USER)

  def invoke(self, arg, from_tty):
    pagination = gdb.parameter("pagination")
    ...

BugReport()
```